Given Q=80-4P where MC=0, Q=Q_1+Q_2+Q_3+...+Q_n, find the reaction curve for firm A,B, and C
Does the condtion Q=Q_1+Q_2+Q_3+...+Q_n affect the process of finding the reaction curves and cournot equilibrium or do we treat it as if were given the condition of Q=Q_1+Q_2+Q_3??
